# RC circuit with time varying capacitor

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

I am considering a series RC circuit with a voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDL5OM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The capacitance of the capacitor varies with time. I am doubtful if this RC circuit should be called a linear circuit.

According to the definition, a linear circuit obeys superposition principle. The RC circuit with variable capacitor still obeys superposition principle at any instant of time.

On the other hand, traditional analysis techniques for linear circuits may not be applicable for the analysis of this RC circuit.

So, is this RC circuit with variable capacitance, a linear or a non linear circuit?

Comment: What does TI stand for in LTI?

Comment: This isn't time invariant, it is rather time varying. So, not an LTI (Linear time invariant), but a non linear time variant? Then there are linear time varying systems also? How do you differentiate?

Comment: @AdnanAli In order to vary the capacitance, work must either be added or subtracted from the circuit. So there is an unknown, external source/sink of work energy that is not shown in the diagram.

Comment: @jonk, I am trying to keep the circuit simple. Moreover, I could not find an additional symbol in the schematics sections. Please accept my simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure we're on the same page, let's recall the definitions of linear and time-invariant device/systems:

- A device or system is said to be *linear* if and only if its zero-state response always satisfies the superposition principle, or equivalently the homogeneity and additivity properties, valid for all time, all scaling constants and all possible pair of inputs.

  - A device or system is said to be *homogeneous* or to satisfy the *homogeneity property* if and only if scaling the input by some constant is the same as scaling the zero-state response by that same constant, valid for all time and all scaling constants.
  - A device or system is said to be *additive* or to satisfy the *additivity property* if and only if the zero-state response due to a sum of two inputs is the same as the sum of the zero-state responses due to the individual inputs, valid for all time and all possible pair of inputs.
  - A device or system is said to satisfy the *superposition principle* if and only if the zero-state response due to a linear combination of two inputs is the same as the linear combination of the zero-state responses due to the individual inputs, valid for all time, all scaling constants and all possible pair of inputs.
- A device or system is said to be *time-invariant* if and only if shifting in time its zero-state response by some constant always results in only shifting in time its zero-state response by that same constant, valid for all time, all possible inputs, and all possible time shifts.

The following figures clarify these concepts.

[image: Block diagram of test for linear system]

*Figure 1. Block diagram illustrating the test for the linearity of a device or system. The system is linear if and only if \$y_3(t) = a_1 y_1(t) + a_2 y_2(t)\$ for all inputs \$x_1(t)\$ and \$x_2(t)\$, all scaling constants \$a_1\$ and \$a_2\$, and for all time \$t\$. Image source: own.*

[image: Block diagram of test for time-invariant system]

*Figure 2. Block diagram illustrating the test for the time invariance of a device or system. The system is time-invariant if and only if \$y_2(t) = y_1(t - t_0)\$ for all input \$x_1(t)\$, all time shift \$t_0\$ and all time \$t\$. Image source: own.*

For bibliographical references on the above definitions, you can read pages 131-134 of *Signals and Systems_ Analysis Using Transform Methods and MATLAB®* (3rd ed.) by Michael J. Roberts; pages 27-28 of *MIMO Signals and Systems* by Horst Bessai; and pages 71 and 74 of *Signals, Systems, and Transforms* (4th ed.) by Charles L. Phillips, John M. Parr and Eve A. Riskin.

---

The following statements can be proven to be true from the definition of a *linear device* and a *time-invariant device* (the word *ideal* in the following means the device doesn't have parasitic properties, it won't mean its property is constant):

- An ideal two-terminal resistor, capacitor and inductor of constant resistance, capacitance and inductance are linear time-invariant devices. So the superposition theorem can be used.
- An ideal two-terminal resistor, capacitor and inductor whose resistance, capacitance and inductance are a function of time only are linear time-variant devices. So the superposition theorem can still be used.
- An ideal two-terminal resistor, capacitor and inductor whose resistance, capacitance and inductance are a function of current and/or voltage and/or charge and/or magnetic flux linkage are non-linear devices. So the superposition theorem can't be used, unless we use a valid linear approximation of the devices, or the devices are operating in a linear region. Furthermore, if the resistance, capacitance and inductance are independent of time, then those devices are additionally time-invariant; but if they are a function of time, then they are time-variant.

I've proven the above statements in Quora. If you're interested, you may read the following:

- Regarding capacitors:

  - [Deriving the voltage-current relation of an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance 1) is constant, or 2) is a function of time only, or 3) is a function of voltage, current and time only](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-current-voltage-equation-of-a-capacitor-whose-capacitance-is-a-function-of-voltage-current-and-time/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).
  - [Proving an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance is constant, is a linear device. Proving an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance is a function of time only, is a linear device. Proving an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance is a function of voltage, current and time only, is a non-linear device](https://www.quora.com/Is-Capacitor-linear-or-nonlinear/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).
  - [Proving an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance is constant, is a time-invariant device. Proving an ideal two-terminal capacitor whose capacitance is a function of time only, is a time-variant device](https://www.quora.com/Is-a-capacitor-a-time-invariant-or-a-time-variant-device/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).
- Regarding inductors:

  - [Deriving the voltage-current relation of an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is 1) constant, or 2) is a function of time only, or 3) is a function of voltage, current and time only](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-voltage-current-equation-of-an-inductor-whose-inductance-is-a-function-of-voltage-current-and-time-1/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).
  - [Proving an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is constant, is a linear device. Proving an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is a function of time only, is a linear device. Proving an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is a function of voltage, current and time only, is a non-linear device](https://www.quora.com/Is-inductor-linear-or-nonlinear/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).
  - [Proving an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is constant, is a time-invariant device. Proving an ideal two-terminal inductor whose inductance is a function of time only, is a time-variant device](https://www.quora.com/Is-an-inductor-a-time-invariant-or-a-time-variant-device/answer/Alejandro-Nava-2).

---

Now, let's address your question.

> The capacitance of the capacitor varies with time. I am doubtful if
> this RC circuit should be called a linear circuit.
>
> So, is this RC circuit with variable capacitance, a linear or a non
> linear circuit?

If the capacitance varies *only* with time, then that's a linear time-variant capacitor. If the resistance is constant or is a function of time only, then that's a linear time-invariant or linear time-variant resistor respectively. So **the *RC* network is linear time-variant**. (It is time-variant because of the capacitor, whether the resistor is time-invariant or time-variant.) So you can apply the superposition theorem.

> According to the definition, a linear circuit obeys superposition
> principle. The RC circuit with variable capacitor still obeys
> superposition principle at any instant of time.

Correct.

> On the other hand, traditional analysis techniques for linear circuits
> may not be applicable for the analysis of this RC circuit.

The thing is that most electric circuit theory/analysis textbooks treat with linear *time-invariant* circuits, yet the books refer to them simply as linear circuits (which is true, but not specific enough).

For example, phasor analysis is applicable assuming 1) sinusoidal sources all of same frequency, 2) the circuit is operating in steady-state, and 3) that the devices are linear *time-invariant*; even if the resistors, inductors and capacitors are linear, you won't be able to apply phasor analysis if the devices are time-variant. (We can still apply phasors analysis if the sinusoidal sources are of different frequency by using phasors + superposition theorem, and we can even apply if there are periodic non-sinusoidal sources by using phasors + superposition + Fourier series.)

The Laplace transform is still quite useful for linear time-variant circuits, so you may use it to solve the circuit; of course you can also solve it directly in the time-domain. You will most probably need to know how the capacitance changes with time, instead of treating it as a generic expression \$C(t)\$.

Comment: For further knowledge and to improve understanding, I would be interested to see the proofs to the statements in your answer. So, please share the link you mentioned.

Comment: @AdnanAli Done.

Answer (score 2):

It is a “ linear, continuous-time, time-<s>in</s>variant system ” circuit with an exponential current response. There are no non-linear resistive components.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please elaborate the three segments linear, continuous-time and time-invariant with respect to the RC circuit under consideration?

Comment: Tony: The circuit is time-variant, not time-invariant.

Comment: @AdnanAli The circuit is linear because it satisfies the superposition principle, or equivalently because it satisfies both the homogeneity (of first degree) and additivity properties. The circuit is time-variant (unlike what Tony said) because shifting the input by some constant in time doesn't result in only shifting the output in time by that same constant. The circuit is continuous-time because the independent variable, time, is continuous; between any two instants of time (e.g. t = 1 s and t = 2 s) there are infinitely many instants (e.g. 1.1 s, 1.01 s, 1.001 s, 1.0001 s, etc.).